# Why is my Mandelbrot-recursion only printing nonsense?

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

#define N_MAX 12

int Mandelbrot_equation (double x, double y, int n, double Zn) {
  if (cabs(Zn) >= 2 || n >= N_MAX) return n;
  if (n == 0) Zn = 0;
  else {
    Zn = cpow(Zn, 2 + 0 * I) + x + I * y;
  }
  Mandelbrot_equation(x, y, n + 1, Zn);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  for (double y = -2.0; y < 1.0; y += 0.1) {
    for (double x = -1.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.1) {
      if (Mandelbrot_equation(x,y,0,0) == N_MAX) printf(".");
      else{
        printf(" ");
      }
      if (x == 0.9) printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, i've tried to implement the Mandelbrot recursion and print it to the screen.
The problem is that the out put looks as follows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0LPe.png

Did I mess up with the recursion or the equation just wrong?

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Post text as text. Read this : [ask]

Comment: Zn is not complex

Comment: Maybe you can add what the expected output looks like (?)

Comment: Your compiler should warn you that you are not returning value from `Mandelbrot_equation()`. Always pay attention to compiler messages.

Comment: May I ask why you choose to implement it as a recursive function rather than using a simple loop?

Answer (score 2):

Three crude errors:

1. `Zn` parameter should be complex:

```
int Mandelbrot_equation (double x, double y, int n, double Zn) {
```

should be:

```
int Mandelbrot_equation (double x, double y, int n, complex Zn) {
```

2. Missing `return` in `Mandelbrot_equation()`.

```
  }
  Mandelbrot_equation(x, y, n + 1, Zn);
}
```

to

```
  }
  return Mandelbrot_equation(x, y, n + 1, Zn);
}
```

3. Newline condition.

Condition `if (x == 0.9) printf("\n");` in never going to be satisfied because number `0.9` cannot be represented with floating point arithmetic. One should use either an integer or inequality operator. However, the best way it to move the newline printer to the outside `y` loop.

Replace:

```
for (double x = -1.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.1) {
      if (Mandelbrot_equation(x,y,0,0) == N_MAX) printf(".");
      else{
        printf(" ");
      }
      if (x == 0.9) printf("\n");
    }
```

with

```
for (double x = -1.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.1) {
      if (Mandelbrot_equation(x,y,0,0) == N_MAX) printf(".");
      else{
        printf(" ");
      }
      
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Result:

```
                     
                     
        .            
          .          
         .           
        ...          
        ...          
    ...........      
    ..........       
   ...........       
.. ............      
...............      
..............       
..............       
..............       
...............      
.. ............      
   ...........       
    ..........       
    ...........      
        ...          
        ...          
         .
```

---

#### EDIT

Replacing ranges with:

```
for (double y = -1.5; y < 1.5; y += 0.1) {
    for (double x = -2.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.05) {
```

and printing `#` rather than `.` makes it look even cooler:

```
                                                            
                                    #                       
                                        #                   
                                     ##                     
                                   ######                   
                                   ######      #            
                            #####################           
                           #####################            
               #           ##################### #          
                ######    #######################           
                #################################           
            ####################################            
 ##############################################             
            ####################################            
                #################################           
                ######    #######################           
               #           ##################### #          
                           #####################            
                            #####################           
                                   ######      #            
                                   ######                   
                                     ##                     
                                        #                   
                                    #
```

Comment: It is bad form to use `for (double x = -1.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.1)` because the C standard and various floating-point formats and arithmetic do not guarantee whether the loop will have 200 or 201 iterations. An alternative is `for (double counter = 0; counter < 200; ++counter) { double x = (counter-100)/10;… }`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yes, but it's a lesser error. The original program has `if (x == 0.9) printf("\n");` which condition is "difficult" to satisfy. I've just tried to minimize changes to the original code